# Get particular columns value for dynamic rows in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm creating dynamic table using php , i my screenshot there is two rows with several columns ,In both the rows, each column has same id (eg:for column monday has id="mon" for first row and id="mon" for second row) , if i enter monday for fisrt row , during on blur i want to fetch that entered value on first rows monday column and also that same rows project name (Timesheet) .

Can anyone please help me ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a piece of advice, don't use the same id in different elements. The "id" attribute was designed to be unique in your DOM. Use "class" instead.

For what you're explaining...

```
$('td input').blur(function() {
    var inputValue = $(this).val();
    var idThisColumn = $(this).parent('td').attr('id');
    var projectName = $(this).closest('tr').children('td').first().children('div.projecttitle').text();
});
```

Your'e not showing how the title is formated inside of the first td, so I'm giving you an example in case is something like...

```
<td>
    <div class="projecttitle">Timesheet</div>
    <div class="projectdesc">Dashboard Design</div>
</td>
```

... but use the selector you need for your case.

**EDITED:**

Ok, now you've sended me the format of the first column...

```
<td>
    <b><div class="projecttitle">{{$currentweek->project_name}}</div></b‌​>
</td>
```

And you want the content inside of the div, so...

```
var projectName = $(this).closest('tr').children('td').first().find('div.projecttitle').text();
```

I hope it helps

Comment: What info do you need? If you need the id of the blured input...

$(this).attr('id');

Let me know what specific data you need

Comment: if i enter for monday i need monday column id and value and also that rows project name.

Comment: That's what I'm giving to you. Let's do something, edit your question and instead of a picture of the table, paste the HTML code of the table, and let me know what attributes or values you need from that code.

Comment: Yeah your code is working for getting the value , i cant able to fetch value of that rows project name  in this code .............                                                                            var projectName = $(this).closest('tr').children('td').first().children('div.projecttitle').text();

Comment: As I explain in the answer, that's propably because I don't know how the project name is formated inside of the first column. I'me giving you one example. If you show me the "td" of the first column (where the project name is), I could do it exactly.

Comment: <td ><b><div class="projecttitle">{{$currentweek->project_name}}</div></b></td>    this is the td .. can you please suggest me how to fetch the rows project name..

Comment: Great! Have fun and happy coding!!